# bootstrap-ui datepicker not refreshing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to get bootstrap-ui's [datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) to display it's popup with an onclick without a function

```
  <input class="form-control" name="dob" type="text"
    datepicker-popup ng-model="user.dateOfBirth"
    is-open="opened" max="maxDate"
    placeholder="Your DOB" required>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" ng-click="opened = !opened">
      <i class="glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
```

It correctly sets the value but won't display the datepicker until something else causes a cycle.

Comment: Please define "to work" in this case.  What behavior do you expect to see?  What are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to make it more clear. It's suppose to display a pop over that has a calendar but with the code above it doesn't until I switch tabs.

Comment: Does it work if you use an onClick function?  Which version of Bootstrap / UI Bootstrap are you using?  I've seen issues w/ earlier versions of Bootstrap and UI Bootstrap that do not exist in the current release of each.  Can you provide a plunker to demo the problem?

Comment: If I copy their example exactly it works. I think the bootstrap-ui isn't actually the issue when I print `{{ opened }}` it doesn't update right away.